# How to use unittest.mock to mock arbitrary ConfigParser calls in a unit test

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking, python-3.3

I'm trying to start using [unittest.mock](http://docs.python.org/3/library/unittest.mock.html)'s action/assert pattern instead of [mox](https://code.google.com/p/pymox/wiki/MoxDocumentation)'s record/replay/verify pattern.

```
# foo.py
def op_1(param):
    pass

def op_2(param):
    pass

def do_stuff(param_1, param_2):
    global config
    global log
    try:
        op_1(param_1)
        if config.getboolean('section','option'):
            op_2(param_2)
    except:
         log.error("an error occured")
```

And, here's an example of what my unittest file looks like.

```
# test_foo.py
class TestFoo(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_do_stuff(self):
        param_1 = None
        param_2 = None
        foo.config = MagicMock()
        foo.config.getboolean('section','option', return_value = True)
        foo.op_1 = MagicMock()
        foo.op_2 = MagicMock()
        do_stuff(param_1, param_2)
        foo.op_1.assert_called_once_with(param_1)
        foo.op_2.assert_called_once_with(param_2)
        foo.config.getboolean.assert_called_once_with('section','option')
```

Does this test to verify the items below/am I using mock right?

1. do_stuff call returned without error
2. op_1 was called with param_1
3. op_2 was called with param_2
4. config parser object had been used, but the specific calls don't matter

Comment: am glad [this was reopened](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/160401)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that I was using the `return_value` wrong.

When I need a `mock.Mock` or `mock.MagicMock` object to return a value, it will need to always return that value, regardless of the arguments passed.  Though, it might be nice to give different behavior based on arguments passed (*possible feature request*).

The way I completed this was:

```
foo.config.getboolean = mock.MagicMock(return_value = True)
```

And then I can do this:

```
self.assertGreaterThan(len(foo.config.mock_calls), 0)
self.assertGreaterThan(len(foo.config.getboolean(str(),str())), 0)
```

Comment: FWIW, if you set `side_effect` to a function, it will be invoked with the arguments to the mock. You can use that to provide different return values from different inputs. See the example for `side_effect` at the beginning of http://www.voidspace.org.uk/python/mock/#quick-guide for a good illustration.